# Fourier series and differential equations (vibrating string)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

We consider a vibrating string. Its movement $u(x,t)$ satisfying the wave equations : $$
 \dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d^2 u}{dx^2},\qquad u(-\pi,t)=u(\pi,t), \qquad u(x,0)= u_0(x),\qquad \dfrac{du}{dt}(x,0)=0.
$$

where the initial condition $u_0(x)$ is the restriction at $[-\pi,\pi]$ of a periodic $C^{\infty}$ function.

I have to "cut" $u(.,t)$ in Fourier serie to give a solution of the wave equation.

I wrote $u(.,t) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k \cos(kt) + b_k \sin(kt)$ and its derivative $u'(.,t) = \sum_{k \geq 1} kb_k \cos(kt) - k a_k \sin(kt)$ and finally, $u''(.,t)= \sum_{k \geq 1} -k^2 a_k \cos(kt) - k^2 b_k \sin(kt)$.

Someone could help me ? I usually work with one variable and not with two variables, so I don't know how to approach the problem. Could someone help me ? I hope my English is understandable.

Comment: What do you mean by $u(.,t)$? Shouldn't it be $u(x,t)$?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the last initial conditions be $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0$$

Comment: Yes, that's it ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you actually need to do is to solve this **partial differential equation (PDE)** by the Fourier method. The method is based on assuming that some particular solution can be represented as:

$$u_p(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$$

Then we have from the PDE:

$$f g''=f'' g$$

Dividing by $f g$ we have:

$$\frac{g''}{g}=\frac{f''}{f}$$

Because the left hand side depends only on $t$, while the right hand side depends only on $x$, they both should be equal to some constant, which we can choose freely (I name it $- \omega^2$):

$$\frac{g''}{g}=\frac{f''}{f}=- \omega^2$$

The solutions can be written as (I use complex exponentials instead of trigonometric functions, it doesn't really matter):

$$g(t)=A(\omega) e^{i \omega t}+B(\omega) e^{-i \omega t}$$

$$f(x)=C(\omega) e^{i \omega x}+D(\omega) e^{-i \omega x}$$

Because we are restricted to the functions with period $2 \pi$, we can only have integer frequencies:

$$\omega = n=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \ldots$$

So:

$$g_n(t)=A_n e^{i n t}+B_n e^{-i n t}$$

$$f_n(x)=C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x}$$

So the general solution should look like a kind of Fourier series:

> $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty \left(A_n e^{i n t}+B_n e^{-i n t} \right) \left(C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x} \right)$$

We can set one of the amplitudes to $1$ without the loss of generality.

Now let's look at the last initial condition:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty i n \left(A_n e^{i n t}-B_n e^{-i n t} \right) \left(C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x} \right)=$$

For $t=0$ we have:

$$=\sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty i n \left(A_n -B_n \right) \left(C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x} \right)=0$$

Which can only work if for every $n$ we have:

$$A_n=B_n$$

Which means $g_n(t)$ are cosines and we can rewrite the function as:

> $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty \cos nt  \left(C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x} \right)$$

We set $A_n=\frac{1}{2}$ without the loss of generality and used the Euler formula $e^{ia}=\cos a+i \sin a$.

Now the final initial condition is:

$$u(x,0)=\sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty \left(C_n e^{i n x}+D_n e^{-i n x} \right)=u_0(x)$$

Now we just need to expand $u_0(x)$ in a Fourier series and match the coefficients to find $C_n$ and $D_n$.